# How to print only date with module dateutil?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I want to print date format when I type numbers but when I use module `dateutil` parser it prints date with time, but I want only date. How to do it? The code:

```
from dateutil import parser

data3 = parser.parse(input("Date of birth (yyyymmdd): "))
print(data3)
```

Output:

```
1900-12-23 00:00
```

Comment: Your posted code prints nothing: it hangs waiting for input.  We are not going to provide your test data.  What happened when you tried to specify your desired format, per `dateutil` documentation?  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: I think nothing happened I just forgot to add print(data3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the strftime function with the following parameters

```py
from dateutil import parser
data3 = parser.parse(input("Date of birth (yyyymmdd): "))
data3.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: hmm nothing changed the same output

Comment: Run the first 2 lines first, then run the 3rd line to retrieve the output?

Comment: Ok it works thank you very much!!!